# Pass params to binary inside Dockerfiles used in Github Action withput using bash

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

can you tell me, what I have to do, when I use a binary that was built from Go, as my entrypoint? I understand how I can use the input params from my github action in a bash script. This basically is plain bash. But how can I pass my input to my binary?

My action.yml

```yaml
---
name: Semantic Version Github Action
description: Github Action to streamline Release Workflows with Semantic Version Validation for Accurate and Consistent Versioning
inputs:
  command:
    description: The semver command that should be run
    default: ""
    required: true
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'src/main/Dockerfile'
  args:
    - ${{ inputs.command }}
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.20-rc-alpine AS build
LABEL maintainer="sebastian@sommerfeld.io"

COPY app /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN go mod download \
    && go test ./... \
    && go build .

FROM alpine:3.18.2 AS run
LABEL maintainer="sebastian@sommerfeld.io"

COPY --from=build app/semver /usr/bin/semver

ARG USER=semver
RUN adduser -D $USER

USER $USER
# ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/semver $INPUT_COMMAND" ] # -> Not working
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/semver" ] # -> This only prints the apps help but does not trigger anything real
```

The releant part of my workflow.yml

```yaml
# [...]
jobs:
  semver:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # [...]
      - name: Validate version
        uses: sommerfeld-io/semver-action@main
        with:
          command: validate ${{ github.event.inputs.version }}
# [...]
```

Anyone got an idea how I can pas my input param to my Go app?

Comment: As you're using `args`, you should be able to access that using `$1` in your entry point script/app similar to the [official example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action#writing-the-action-code). In your Go app, you can use that via command line arguments i.e. using `os.Args`. You can write your own Bash script as an entrypoint to handle this and then run the Go app internally.

Comment: Thanks man ... that did it ... I thought about this earlier but had a flaw in my thinking. Adding an entrypoint.sh and calling the binary with params from there works. If anyone is interested in my action, see https://github.com/sommerfeld-io/semver-action